# Problem finding AncestorType in ControlTemplate.Triggers

Tags: wpf, xaml

Im trying to make a `Clip`'ped `ToggleButton` to spin itself, not its `Content`, upon `Checked` event.
I have my `AttachedProperty` like this:

```
public class Extensions
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RotationAngleCheckedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "RotationAngleChecked",
        typeof(double),
        typeof(Extensions),
        new PropertyMetadata(0.0));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RotationAngleUncheckedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "RotationAngleUnchecked",
        typeof(double),
        typeof(Extensions),
        new PropertyMetadata(0.0));

    public static void SetRotationAngleUnchecked(UIElement element, double value)
    {
        element.SetValue(RotationAngleUncheckedProperty, value);
    }

    public static double GetRotationAngleUnchecked(UIElement element)
    {
        return (double)element.GetValue(RotationAngleUncheckedProperty);
    }

    public static void SetRotationAngleChecked(UIElement element, double value)
    {
        element.SetValue(RotationAngleCheckedProperty, value);
    }

    public static double GetRotationAngleChecked(UIElement element)
    {
        return (double)element.GetValue(RotationAngleCheckedProperty);
    }

}
```

`Style` for the `ToggleButton` uses `ControlTemplate.Triggers` to change `RotateTransform.Angle` based upon `Binding`:

```
<Style x:Key="StyleToggleButtonTriangleS" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">
    <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
    <Setter Property="Clip" Value="{StaticResource GeometryGroupTriangleClipS}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border x:Name="Border" CornerRadius="3" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    </ContentPresenter>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BrushForegroundBlue}"/>
                        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Path=(ext:Extensions.RotationAngleChecked), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ToggleButton}}"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BrushForegroundMain}"/>
                        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Path=(ext:Extensions.RotationAngleUnchecked), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ToggleButton}}"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

`ToggleButton` used like this:

```
<!-- xmlns:ext="clr-namespace:MyProject.Extensions" -->

<ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButtonSpeedSelection" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="38"
              VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              ext:Extensions.RotationAngleChecked="-45"
              ext:Extensions.RotationAngleUnchecked="135"
              Style="{StaticResource StyleToggleButtonTriangleS}">
</ToggleButton>
```

Now my issue is that it actually works, `ToggleButton` spins, but Output window shows an error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with
>   reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor,
>   AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton',
>   AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=(0); DataItem=null; target
>   element is 'RotateTransform' (HashCode=54095401); target property is
>   'Angle' (type 'Double')

How can I fix that error?

Comment: Have you tried with `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}` instead of `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ToggleButton}`?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski yes, stops working (spinning) then